# Custom column in dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

Problem is, I'm trying to create a customize column like the results of a blood test.

For Example:

```
------|--*------|------
```

Where

```
 ----- is full values range 
 * sampled data
 First '|' is minimum value
 Last '|' is maximum value
```

Of course when sampled data is under min or over max, i want to paint it in `red`.

The following link can show more clearly the type of table that I'm trying to make:
http://www.lbs.co.il/threads/17433/
Hope this will help..

I tried to do this with a `progress bar`
But its not optimal. Since I can't display values that exceed the limits.

Can you please send me a reference for something similar?

Thanks,

Comment: can you explain more about below lines which you said :            "------|--*------|------ 
Where ----- is full values range * sampled data First '|' is minimum value Last '|' is maximum value"

Comment: Explain with Sample data

Comment: what are you using ? winforms/wpf?

Comment: Lets say I want to show the Hemoglobin level in my blood, good values are between 12 and 16. My sample was 10.7 g/dl and I want to show on a bar the range along with my result that was under the minimum.. Is there a way to upload a picture to this query..??

Comment: Sorry for not writing... I'm using winForms, c#. And want to display the table in a form and later send it to word doc.

Comment: do you want to print a image in minimum and maximum column?.

Comment: I want to create a table that has: column1, string, description / column2, double, sampled data / column3, customized, bar that graphically shows the value along with its limits... I want to show the table in a form and later to write it to a word document. If its possible, I can upload here a "demo" how the table can be look like..

Comment: I've put a link to a picture on the internet that can show a similar table of what I ment..

Comment: No one has the answer? Or no one wants to help me??